# Linux Mint: Unable to uninstall / remove virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I'm using Linux Mint 17 and I have to uninstall virtualbox-4.3 from the system, but it's giving me the following error.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-4.3

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  virtualbox-4.3*

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 155 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

(Reading database ... 194033 files and directories currently installed.)

Removing virtualbox-4.3 (4.3.12-93733~Ubuntu~raring) ...
/etc/init.d/vboxdrv: 85: .: Can't open /etc/init.d/functions
invoke-rc.d: initscript vboxdrv, action "stop" failed.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-4.3 (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2

Errors were encountered while processing:

 virtualbox-4.3

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help, i will be thankful to you.

Comment: Try creating the missing file: sudo touch /etc/init.d/functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upstream VirtualBox packages contain an init script that tries to detect your distribution. It isn't doing a good job on your system: it's looking for `/etc/init.d/functions`, which should be a Red Hat thing, on a Debian-based system.

Since you're purging the package, rather than try to fix the script, it's simpler to work around it. Add the following lines at the top of the file `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv`:

```
#!/bin/sh
rmmod vboxpci vboxnetadp vboxnetflt vboxdrv
rm /dev/vboxdrv
exit 0
```

and run

```
apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-4.3
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i tried it, thanks it worked..so happy..thanks a ton :)

Answer (score -1):

First run:

```
sudo yum list installed | grep virtualbox
```

This will show something like:

```
VirtualBox-5.0.x86_64        5.0.10_104061_el7-1      @virtualbox
```

Then to remove, just run:

Comment: seems you forgot to add last line

Comment: Not to mention that the question is for Mint, which isn't RedHat-based and doesn't have or use yum, and apt-get had in fact identified the correct package, that wasn't the problem, which was correctly solved over a year ago.